# How to conditionally include page elements in form tag

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Working in C#, Visual Studio 2012, MVC4 EF.

I have a view that, when a condition is met, I want to be a form.  How do I do this without having to have one section with the page elements in a form, and another section with the same page elements not in a form?

Here is my code for the condition:

```
        @if (this.Model.ItemRequestStatusId == Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.VendorRepReview
        && this.User.IsInRole("Vendor Rep"))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ItemRequest", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

        <button id="btn-data-integrity-final-review" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" type="submit">Vendor Review Complete</button>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit this request", "Edit", new { id = this.Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default pull-right" })
    }
```

and then below that condition, I have the page elements/fields.  But they currently don't fall within the form (only the submit button is within the form).  I want to capture the fields in POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to use javascript. For example you could subscribe to the `submit` event of this form and then clone all the fields into the form before submitting:

```
$('#formId').submit(function() {
    var inputFields = $('#someDivContainingYourInputFields').clone();
    $(this).append(inputFields);
});
```

But a better approach would be to simply organize your markup in such a way that the input fields are inside the form. You could achieve that by moving the form definition outside of the condition and wrap the input fields with it. Only the submit button could stay inside the if.

Comment: so, let me make sure i understand your "better approach" suggestion.  the Edit button would be inside of the form, but no POST would happen because the submit button is only displayed when the condition is met.  right?